# Get information of P7S file with openssl

Tags: openssl

I have a .p7s file that I know that there is a PDF file embeded in it, the signer's certificate and timestamp information.

So, there is this little program called [P7S Viewer](https://www.signfiles.com/p7s-viewer/), and it can show me all the information I need, specially the issuer name, subject name, the signature time, the time stamp server and time.

[image: P7S Viewer]

How can I get all this information using openssl? I've managed only to extract the pdf file inside the p7s I have, but not much else. Specially the time stamp information, I could not extract anything.

Answer (score 4):

You want to use the openssl [cms](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/cms.html) command.

A p7s is just a signature file in DER format.  There is no "content" in that file, it's normally apart of a S/MIME message as a base64 attachment.

To dump the structure of a .p7s you would use the following command:

> openssl cms -cmsout -in file.p7s -inform DER -noout -print